# Show Progressbar while downloading file from Dropbox

Tags: iphone, download, dropbox

In my application I want to show Progressbar while downloading file from Dropbox.
Which method I use to download file ?
1) ASIHTTPRequest (but it requires URL to download)
2) DBRequest (but it requires URLRequest)
3) [[self restClient] loadFile:file.path intoPath:localPath (but how to show progress bar?)

Thanks,

Comment: Note that many apps, including the native Mail and iMessage applications, do not use real progress bars.  Instead they use fake progress bars to give the user a sense of activity.  The bar starts at about 10%, then slowly begins to progress towards 90%.  If the task finishes before it reaches 90%, the bar zips along the rest of the way.  If the task takes longer, the bar stops at 90% until the task completes, and then it finishes the last 10%.

Comment: Okay, So I also display fake progressbar. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Because you mention `loadFile`, I assume you're using the Core SDK. In that case, you'll want to implement the `loadProgress` delegate method.

From `DBRestClient.h`:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadProgress:(CGFloat)progress
                                              forFile:(NSString*)destPath;
```